# Difference between named entity recognition and resolution?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

What is the difference between named entity recognition and named entity resolution? Would appreciate a practical example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Named entity recognition is picking up the names and classifying them in running text. E.g., given ([1](http://www.guardian.co.uk/football/2011/dec/21/john-terry-racism-case-cps))

```
John Terry to face criminal charges over alleged racist abuse
```

an NE recognizer will output

```
[PER John Terry] to face criminal charges over alleged racist abuse
```

NE resolution or normalization means finding out which entity in the outside world a name refers to. E.g., in the above example, the output would be annotated with a unique identifier for the footballer John Terry, like his Wikipedia URL:

```
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Terry John Terry] to face criminal charges
over alleged racist abuse
```

as opposed to, e.g.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Terry_%28actor%29
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Terry_%28baseball%29
```

or any of the other John Terry's the Wikipedia knows.